# Nest js commit problems to github

Tags: github, nestjs

Created a Nest.js project with using nest new and when I went to commit it on github using github desktop it says that the file is empty when its clearly not. Tried using git add . and it says
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQPKQ.png)
Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtTGe.png) tried this but it did nothing. Dont even know what it was suppose to do read it on another post on stackoverflow

Comment: do you have a proper .gitignore in directory ? if not make one and make sure to inlclude all files like /dist .env

Comment: I have one. As soon as I make a nest js project I cant commit it without any changes.
When I make a new nest app it makes a gitignore itself, tried deleteing it it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution but don't know why it works. When I start a new project I add
--skip-git and then I manually add .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a Git repository has been started in the Nest.js project's root directory. You can do this by running the command `git init` in the project's root directory.

Comment: I have. I cant commit anything when when its a nest project

Answer (score 0):

Add `dist/` in `.gitignore` file and it must ignore all the production build which are taking up all the spaces.
Also, you need to unstage all the changes if already added the `dist/` folder to the staging area with the command `git reset`.